# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling managedObjectContext save

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access

Occasionally I get this error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x13421772123
```

It happens on the save: line below (in a CoreDataController singleton class)

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
```

I know this isn't a lot of code to go from, but from experience is there common cause to this, and any way to prevent this from crashing the app?

Comment: Yes, this is an ARC app.

Comment: Which thread is running this code?

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext Queue Crashed

Comment: Called from com.apple.root.background-priority

Comment: Are you using the NSManagedObjectContext on a thread other than the thread where it was created?

Comment: Not that I can tell...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if managedObjectContext is the main context, then you should call it in main thread, try wrap it with following code, incase you call it in a background thread

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm getting this: Sending 'NSError *const __strong *' to parameter of type 'NSError *__autoreleasing *' changes retain/release properties of pointer

Comment: just moved error declaration to block to avoid the error, see updated codes        alternative way is declaring the error as     __block NSError *error = nil;

Comment: Marking this correct for now, since I haven't had the crash yet.

Comment: Sometimes my code was crashing in [self saveContext];
Apparently, i replaced my code in saveContext method by this one, and now its crashing EVERYTIME I call [self saveContext]. What to do!?

Comment: This still crashes for me. anyone got a solution?

Comment: It doesn't need to be on the main thread, but it does need to be on the thread on which the managed object was created. Fortunately, you can ask the object for its context. If you already have the object, get the context from the object and call save on that context. That will perform the block on the appropriate thread.

Comment: Apparently, you have to **save the context from within the block**, to make sure all data needed by CoreData will be still available